# Edit TextView in Android LayoutInflater

Tags: android

Sorry for using Translater

I want edit TextView and ImageView inside LayoutInflater

But the content doesn't change except for the top one

Looks like view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_...); is pointing same thing

**How I can get TextView inside R.layout.recie_card?**

This is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void showRecipe(RecipeData[] recipe) { 
        LayoutInflater line_inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < recipe.length; i++) {
            Log.d("URL", recipe[i].getImgURL());
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_card, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.recipelist_line1), true);
                ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
                Glide.with(this).load(recipe[i].getImgURL()).into((imageView));
                
                TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_title);
                TextView ingreds = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_ingreds);
                TextView making = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_making);
                title.setText(recipe[i].getTitle());
                ingreds.setText(recipe[i].getStringIngreds());
                making.setText(recipe[i].getStringDescription());
            } else {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_card, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.recipelist_line2), true);
                ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
                Glide.with(this).load(recipe[i].getImgURL()).into((imageView));
                
                TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_title);
                TextView ingreds = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_ingreds);
                TextView making = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_making);
                title.setText(recipe[i].getTitle());
                ingreds.setText(recipe[i].getStringIngreds());
                making.setText(recipe[i].getStringDescription());
            }

        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
...
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/recipelist_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/recipelist_line1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/recipelist_line2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
...
```

**recipe_card.xml**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_ingreds"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="If you see this, data was not loaded" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_making"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum Sed eiusmod esse
aliqua sed incididunt aliqua
incididunt mollit id et sit proident
aliqua cillum in consequat
consequat in culpa in anim." />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You dont need to give layout_weight to your TextView

Comment: Avoid using  tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" in your layout